# Ruby on Rails ActiveStorage image doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an app which works fine before with active storage. But I am not sure what happened but it's no longer working anymore and it's showing a broken image:

[image]

Here's what I did in the past on my contact model:

```
  has_one_attached :contact_avatar
```

And in my `views/index.html.erb`:

```
  <%= image_tag contact.contact_avatar.attached? ? contact.contact_avatar : "100x100.png", class: "media-object img-thumbnail img-rounded mr-3" %>
```

Any idea what's causing this?

**MORE INFO**: Whenever I am trying to insert or upload a photo using ActiveStorage I am always having this on my terminal:

```
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [875b372f-3647-4ba0-8beb-3fe38e8885d3]    (9.6ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [875b372f-3647-4ba0-8beb-3fe38e8885d3]   ↳ /Users/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [875b372f-3647-4ba0-8beb-3fe38e8885d3] Performed ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 875b372f-3647-4ba0-8beb-3fe38e8885d3) from Async(default) in 104.68ms
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--05a842304d7509391444fb7250f49645b77cff00/madman.png" for ::1 at 2020-05-29 13:13:19 +0800
Processing by ErrorsController#page_not_found as PNG
  Parameters: {"path"=>"rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--05a842304d7509391444fb7250f49645b77cff00/madman"}
  Rendering errors/404.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered errors/404.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
```

---

Here's the contact controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @contacts = current_user.contacts.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
    @contacts = @contacts.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
    @contacts = @contacts.search(params[:term]) if params[:term].present?
  end

  def autocomplete
      @contacts = current_user.contacts.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
      @contacts = @contacts.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
      @contacts = @contacts.search(params[:term]) if params[:term].present?
      render json: @contacts.map { |contact| { id: contact.id, value: contact.name }}
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def edit
    authorize @contact
  end

  def create
    @contact = current_user.contacts.build(contact_params)
    @success = @contact.save ? true : false

    respond_to do |format|
      if @success
        format.html { redirect_to contacts_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @success = @contact.update(contact_params) ? true : false

    respond_to do |format|
      if @success
        format.html { redirect_to contacts_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @contact
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :mobile, :phone, :country, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :note, :category_id, :contact_avatar)
    end

    def has_error?(resource, field)
      resource.errors.messages[field].present?
    end

    def get_error(resource, field)
      msg = resource.errors.messages[field]
      field.to_s.capitalize + " " + msg.join(' and ') + '.'
    end

    helper_method :has_error?
    helper_method :get_error
end
```

Here's the `storage.yml` file:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the Azure Storage secret (as azure_storage:storage_access_key)
# microsoft:
#   service: AzureStorage
#   storage_account_name: your_account_name
#   storage_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:azure_storage, :storage_access_key) %>
#   container: your_container_name

# mirror:
#   service: Mirror
#   primary: local
#   mirrors: [ amazon, google, microsoft ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Could you post the part of your routes file pertaining to `ErrorsController#page_not_found`?

I'm guessing that you may have a catch-all route which routes to this controller, which is causing the ActiveStorage routes to never match.

For example if you have something like

```
match '*any', to: 'errors#page_not_found', via: [:get]
```

then you should remove this, and look into configuring [config.exceptions_app](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) instead for serving custom error pages.

Comment: Brilliant. I had an old catch-all that I no longer know why it was there!

Comment: Thank you!! I removed the `match '*path'` and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Add these gems to the gemfile and run bundle

```
#Gemfile
gem 'image_processing'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

You can also need to run 
`sudo apt install imagemagick` in your console afterwards.